# How the assertRedirect() work with an uri?

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 10. And doing my tests with the native test system of laravel.

I do not understand how does the **assertRedirect()** work.

This test is OK :

```
$this->post($this->url)
        ->assertInvalid([
            'name',
        ])
        ->assertRedirect();
```

But this same test failed when I precise an uri :

```
$redirect = '/schools/' . $this->school->id . '/groups/create';
    // dd($redirect);

    $this->post($this->url)
        ->assertInvalid([
            'name',
        ])
        ->assertRedirect($redirect);
```

And the error is :

```
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'http://localhost/schools/99a4b401-d3ea-4308-9178-8a1699d08cd8/groups/create'
+'http://localhost'
```

When I debug the var $redirect, it contains the expected value.
What is my mistake ?

**edit**
The route is very classical

```
Route::resource('schools/{school}/groups', GroupController::class);
```

Comment: try to use the `route('name')`  in the `assertRedirect()` @Dom

Comment: Your test seem to be working! It clearly states that instead of getting the proper redirect `'http://localhost/schools/99a4b401-d3ea-4308-9178-8a1699d08cd8/groups/create'`, it is redirecting to root route `'http://localhost'`. Solutions I can see:
A) Did you not expect the `Location` uri to be validated? (Remove the parameter)
B) Your route is redirecting to the wrong place. This might be caused by a middleware, like authentication check; OR a bug on the route. Please, share the route code and make sure execution is actually getting there.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I tried to test the redirection to a route name `->assertRedirectToRoute("groups.create", ["school" => $this->school]);` without success; Same error. I also checked if there was not an issue with the authentication , and no there is not because when I test this , it is ok `$this->assertAuthenticated()`

Comment: I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63055639/laravel-7-unit-test-to-registration-route-redirects-to-home-page

Answer (score 0):

To validate form input in Laravel tests, you can utilize the assertSessionHasErrors() method available in Laravel's testing framework. This method allows you to assert that the session contains errors for specific form fields.

Here's an example of how you can use it:

```
  $response = $this->post($this->url, [
    'name' => '', // Provide invalid data for the 'name' field
  ]);

 $response->assertSessionHasErrors('name')->assertRedirect($redirect);
```

Comment: I also tried like that , same error